# Does volatile-lru evict all keys with same ttl?

Tags: redis, memory-optimization

I have thousands of related keys set with same ttl.

Once maxmemory is reached, does volatile-lru evict all the keys sharing the same ttl or just what it needs to make space for new data?

Comment: "just what it needs to make space"

Comment: it will remove "least recently used" keys first. Algorithm is here https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache#approximated-lru-algorithm